# DataGridView with Expand/Collapsible Header Column

Tags: c#, datagridview

is there any way to design DataGridView with Expand/Collapsible Header Column ?

output look like

```
               + 2010                 +2011
          ------------------    ---------------------
Days      JAN     FEB    MAR    JAN     FEB     MAR
--------  -------------------   ---------------------
1           11     22     20     87     45       66
2           11     22     20     87     45       66
3           11     22     20     87     45       66
4           11     22     20     87     45       66
5           11     22     20     87     45       66
31          11     22     20     87     45       66
```

when click on (+/-) button then that column will expand & collapse and as well as child columns will be expand & collapse along with parent column.

without using any third part control how can i customize grid for my requirement. please guide me. thanks

Comment: The WinForms one? Not easily without a lot of changes, and even then it might not expose enough of it's innards in order to support the changes.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/195423/DataGridViewExtension

Comment: Certain actions are entirely possible, I'm just saying that it's not easy. The column layering you want sounds almost like a pivot table. I'd advise hunting around for an open source implementation. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3531/SourceGrid-Open-Source-C-Grid-Control